# MongoDB error not master and slaveOk=false

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, loopbackjs

I am using MongoDB with Loopback in my application with a loopback connector to the MongoDB. My application was working fine but now it throws an error

**not master and slaveOk=false**.

Answer (score 4):

try running `rs.slaveOk()` in a mongoDB shell

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to connect to secondary replica whilst previously your app (connection) was set to connect likely to the primary, hence the error. If you use `rs.secondaryOk()` (`slaveOk` is [deprecated](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/info-rs-slave-is-deprecated-use-rs-secondaryok/108435) now) you will possibly solve the connection problem but it might not be what you want.

To make sure you are doing the right thing, think if you want to connect to the secondary replica instead of primary. Usually, it's not what you want.

**If you have permissions to amend the replica configuration**

I suggest to connect using MongoDB Compass and execute `rs.status()` first to see the existing state and configuration for the cluster. Then, verify which replica is *primary*.

If necessary, adjust priorities in the replicaset configuration to assign *primary* status to the right replica. The highest priority number sets the replica as primary. [This article](https://flowygo.com/en/blog/mongodb-and-docker-how-to-create-and-configure-a-replica-set/) shows how to do it right.

**If you aren't able to change the replica configuration**

Try a few things:

- make sure your hostname points to the primary replica
- if it is a local environment issue - make sure you added your local replica hostnames to the /etc/hosts pointing to 127.0.0.1
- experiment with `directConnection=true`
- experiment with multiple replica hosts and `?replicaSet=<name>` - read [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/) (switch tabs to replica)

The best bet is that your database configuration has changed and your connection string no longer reflects it correctly. Usually, slight adjustments in the connection string are needed or just checking to what instance you want to connect.